# Why does a transformation on $p$ imply the inverse transformation on $q$ in phase space?

Tags: coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I'm reading [A conceptual introduction to Hamiltonian Monte Carlo](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02434). On pages 30-31 it is stated that applying a transformation to the momentum p in phase space, implies the opposite transformation to the parameters q:
$$p'= \sqrt{M^{-1}}p$$
implies
$$q'= \sqrt{M}q$$
for some Euclidean metric $M$, known as the mass matrix.

I don't understand why this is. Suppose we are working in 1 dimension (so $M$ is just a number), and suppose $M = 4$. Then:
$$q' = \sqrt{M}q = 2q$$
The momentum would then be:
$$p = mv = m \frac{dq}{dt} = \frac{1}{2} m \frac{dq'}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}p' \iff p' = 2p$$
To me it seems both p and q transform in the same way, getting multiplied by 2. So where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hint: The mass does also transform.

Comment: Think of the trajectory of a classical oscillator in phase space which preserves the energy defining it. How do rescale coordinates and momenta scaling the mass?

Comment: @Qmechanic: Yes! Of course! Another piece of the puzzle for me was to look up that $p = \frac{dL}{d\dot{q}}$ with L the Lagrangian of the system. If we use only kinetic energy then $H = L = T$. If we reparameterize to $q'$, then we can derive $p'$ again from the Lagrangian: $p' = \frac{dL}{d\dot{q'}}$ which gave me the correct answer. If you make a reply including this derivation I will accept it. (Or if you prefer I can do it as well. But I don't want to steal your thunder here ;-).)

Comment: Hi Willem. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in [Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), where we define the Lagrangian to be $L = T - V$ where $T$ is the kinetic energy and $V$ is the potential energy. In our case:
$$
L = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(q) = \frac{mv^2}{2} + V(q) = \frac{m\dot{q}^2}{2} + V(q)
$$
so that:
$$
p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}
$$
If we now apply the transformation $q' = \sqrt{M}q$ (with constant $M$) we get:
$$
p' = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q'}} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial \dot{q'}} = p \frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The author of this statistics paper aims for transformations $p\mapsto p'\,,q\mapsto q'$ that preserve Hamiltonian geometry. As far as I can tell from a quick look at [Hamiltonian Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_Monte_Carlo) this means he wants to preserve the energies expressed as
$$
H=\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol p^\top M^{-1}\boldsymbol p\,,\quad T=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\boldsymbol q}^\top M\dot{\boldsymbol q}\,.
$$
This looks quite familar to a physicist. Now take the square root of $M$ and $M^{-1}\,.$ Clearly, the invariance of $H$ and $T$ under the above transformations is compatible with $\boldsymbol p'=\sqrt{M^{-1}}\boldsymbol p$ and $\dot{\boldsymbol q}'=\sqrt{M}\dot{\boldsymbol q}\,$ and assuming that $M$ is constant we can undo the time derivative of the $\dot{\boldsymbol q}$ relation.